# Spring custom qualifiers not working

Tags: java, spring

Iam trying to deal with custom qualifiers in Spring(4.2.4.RELEASE).

I have an interface:

```
    public interface CompactDisc {
    public void play();
}
```

and 3 implementations:

```
@Component
@Beatles
public class SgtPeppers implements CompactDisc {
    private String title = "Sgt. Pepper's Lonely Hearts Club Band";
    private String artist = "The Beatles";
    public void play() {
        System.out.println("Playing " + title + " by " + artist);
    }
}

@Component
@Metallica
@Metallica1986
public class MasterOfPuppets implements CompactDisc {
    @Override
    public void play() {
        System.out.println("Playing Master Of Puppets by Metallica");
    }
}

@Component
@Metallica
@Metallica1997
public class Fuel implements CompactDisc {
    @Override
    public void play() {
        System.out.println("Fuel by Metallica");
    }
}
```

Also i created 4 custom qualifiers:

```
@Target({ElementType.CONSTRUCTOR, ElementType.FIELD,
        ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Qualifier
public @interface Beatles {
}

@Target({ElementType.CONSTRUCTOR, ElementType.FIELD,
        ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Qualifier
public @interface Metallica {
}


@Target({ElementType.CONSTRUCTOR, ElementType.FIELD,
        ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Qualifier
public @interface Metallica1986 {
}

@Target({ElementType.CONSTRUCTOR, ElementType.FIELD,
        ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Qualifier
public @interface Metallica1997 {
}
```

Test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = CDPlayerConfig.class)
public class CDPlayerTest {

    @Autowired
    @Metallica
    @Metallica1997
    private CompactDisc cd;

    @Test
    public void cdShouldNotBeNull() {
        assertNotNull(cd);
        cd.play();
    }
}
```

Config file:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class CDPlayerConfig {
}
```

But when i run it i see:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type [my.spring.CompactDisc] is defined: expected
>   single matching bean but found 3: fuel,masterOfPuppets,sgtPeppers

Why qualifiers dont work for me?

Comment: Why do you expect them to work in this case?

Comment: Your sample works fine for me.

Comment: I suspected that at injection point with this combination of qualifier annotations i narrowed the selection to the one bean. But it seems its not.

Comment: I've tried with 4.2.4 and it works fine for me.

Comment: I'm voting to close as unreproducible.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem - despite everything being obviously correct, the custom qualifier did not seem to work and Spring complained that the constructor "required a single bean, but 4 were found".

The solution was actually very simple - running `mvn clean` and rebuilding. Sometimes it's the most stupid thing that works.

Edit: I actually faced this problem again and this time the clean did not help. Instead, I discovered that the name of the injected variable must match the name of the method creating the bean.